# Why is IHttpHandler's ProcessRequest method not getting the original URL in the context in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have a class that implements IHttpHandler in a .NET Framework app,
and a `ProcessRequest` method that implements IHttpHandler.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  //some logic
}
```

I added a breakpoint on the first line of `ProcessRequest` to see the values of `context.Request.Path` and `context.Request.Url`. I noticed I never get the URL that launched the app. I get the ones for various `*.css` and `*.js` files that got loaded as assets. For example, the first one was `bootstrap.css`.

Why am I not getting the original URL using `context.Request.Url` or `context.Request.Path`?